# Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I try to numerically solve a first order system of linear ODE's with quite complicated time-dependent coefficients. When I use `NDSolve`, I get an error

> NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}

But when I use this method, evaluation becomes extremely long (actually, I still have no result, even now it's calculating ...). Is there any way, to make it faster or I just have to wait?

I'd like to add that the proposed method  (Residual simplification) doesn't work, because I work with complex functions.

Comment: Problems with code generally require the code for help. -- Have you tried solving for the derivatives yourself (e.g. using `Solve[]`)?

Comment: Actually, code won't help you. My system of ODE looks like a'[t]==K[t]*a[t], (plus initial conditions, of course) where K[t] is a matrix (12x12) with very long formulas. And it is already solved for the derivatives.

Comment: Do you mean `a'[t] == K[t]*a[t]` or `a'[t] == K[t].a[t]`?

Comment: Of course a'[t] == K[t].a[t]

Comment: That sort of thing works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7GvS.png -- Note `K` is a system symbol used by *Mathematica*, but it works with `k` or `K` for me. I have to wonder if there's something else with the code.

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing, that can help me, in your code...

Comment: I didn't actually think it would help. I meant to show that without your code, or further hints about it, there doesn't seem to be anything that can be done. -- For instance, I don't think you can get the error you get with the set-up you describe. So there's something unusual, probably in `K[t]` unless there's an error in your code. At least that's my thinking at present.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution of an error:

```
Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}
```

This one helped me.

Comment: This does seem to work. This is suggested in Mathematica 9, which also gives more useful error: _The time constraint of 1.` seconds was exceeded trying to solve for derivatives, so the system will be treated as a system of differential-algebraic equations. You can use Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} to have the system solved as ordinary differential equations_.